# How could i change the SharePoint Page <Title>?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I am adding a WebPartPage in the Site Pages Library by using following code!

```
public Boolean CreateWebPartPage(string ListName, string pageName)
        {
                Web web = spCtx.Web;
                spCtx.Load(web);
                spCtx.ExecuteQuery();

                List sitePagesList = web.Lists.GetByTitle(ListName);

                spCtx.Load(sitePagesList);
                spCtx.Load(sitePagesList.RootFolder);
                spCtx.Load(sitePagesList.RootFolder.Files);
                spCtx.ExecuteQuery();

                var fileRelativePath = sitePagesList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + pageName;

                if (sitePagesList.RootFolder.Files.Count != 0)
                {
                    for (int iFile = sitePagesList.RootFolder.Files.Count - 1; iFile >= 0; iFile--)
                    {
                        if (sitePagesList.RootFolder.Files[iFile].ServerRelativeUrl == fileRelativePath)
                        {
                            //Deleting already Exist page
                            sitePagesList.RootFolder.Files[iFile].DeleteObject();
                        }
                    }
                    spCtx.ExecuteQuery();
                }

                //Add New Page to "Site Pages"
                sitePagesList.RootFolder.Files.AddTemplateFile(fileRelativePath, TemplateFileType.StandardPage);
                spCtx.ExecuteQuery();
                return true;
    }
```

Page is Successfully Added! but the Problem is : It shows me the  of a page as "Site Pages - Default" at the browser tab.

[image]

I am provide the pageName = "Testing1.aspx" but it not apply to the  tag?
what can i do for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `Title` property after the file is added.

So, modify your code as below:

```
var file = sitePagesList.RootFolder.Files.AddTemplateFile(fileRelativePath, TemplateFileType.StandardPage);
spCtx.Load(file);
spCtx.ExecuteQuery();

var wikiPage = file.ListItemAllFields;
wikiPage["Title"] = pageName;  // "Test1" or whatever is the page name             
wikiPage.Update();
spCtx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: It's not working!

Answer (score 1):

I did not test it but you can try this. I don't know anything about server object model but just found these.

```
// Get a reference to the appropriate Content Placeholder
ContentPlaceHolder contentPlaceHolder = (ContentPlaceHolder) 
                       Page.Master.FindControl("PlaceHolderPageTitle");

// Clear out anything that SharePoint might have put in it already
contentPlaceHolder.Controls.Clear();

// Put your content in
LiteralControl literalControl = new LiteralControl();
literalControl.Text = "Your text goes here";
contentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(literalControl);
```

Found [here](http://chris.gg/2010/02/how-to-set-sharepoint-page-title-programmatically/) and [here](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2007/08/programmatically-setting-a-web-part-pages-title/)

Comment: I am trying CSOM code not Server Object Model code! I am adding new Web Part page using CSOM Console Application in SharePoint online.

Comment: CSOM? Is this not server side code which you shared? :/

Comment: No this is not the Server Side Code! It's CSOM.